# Why Projects made in Swift 3 or lower gives error new Xcode 9 supporting swift 4.1?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Its been a very tough for me to get a suitable answer for this Question as **I know the solution but the reason is still unknown**

Let me explain the question properly, `when we make any projects like in swift 3 or lower version in lower versions of Xcode like 7 or 8`

Its Doest run in new Xcode version like 9 we have to change the **Swift_version** in build settings to make it work.

Why doest it happen why Xcode doesn't support all versions of swift like I can show us **deprecated warning** rather then throwing **error**

```
for Obj c It works in all Xcode whatever Xcode you use it supports Obj c
```

Comment: It works for `Obj-C` because this is stable for a long time and `Swift` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Xcode 9 does not ship with older Swift versions. You need to update your Swift code.

Generally, Xcode also does not support older Obj-C versions, but Obj-C syntax hardly changes from year to year, that is why Obj-C code that you wrote in Xcode 7 runs in Xcode 9. But this was not the case for Obj-C code you wrote in say Xcode 2 or lower.